# Syncing Unsigned Numbers Using Simperium

Tags: ios, simperium

I have a Core Data entity that has an attribute of type integer 32. Everything is fine and dandy when I assign an NSNumber, which is generated from an unsigned int, to the attribute and save the context. I can access the attribute and use the data stored there. However, when I inspect the data in Simperium's dashboard or a device that the entity was synced to, the attribute fails to sync.

Can anyone verify if this is a bug with Simperium or if I just don't understand how to store unsigned ints in Core Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I vaguely recall you CD does not handle unsigned. Convert the number to a string and save it in CD that way. Then provide two methods to convert to and from.

Comment: It appears you are correct: http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg13487.html I probably should have searched for this answer first. Thanks!